# Total number of Bitcoins generated by pool mining

Tags: mining-pools, history

Hi I'm doing some research regarding bitcoins and pool mining, however I couldn't find the following information online.

1. Total number of Bitcoins generated so far by pool mining and how many miners were involved.
2. Total number of Bitcoins generated per day by pool mining and number of miners involved per day.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: You mean pool mining as opposed to solo mining? Would you count big ASIC manufacturers mining by themselves and cloud mining as pool mining?

Comment: Yes I am specifically referring to pool mining only. I would exclude big ASIC manufactures as they are solo miners. If cloud mining involves group of miners working together to share their reward then I would consider cloud mining as pool mining.

Answer (score 1):

http://coinmarketcap.com/ states there are ~13.330.000 bitcoins generated.
you can have a overview of the shares on mining bye pool here: https://blockchain.info/pools

blockchain.info gives most information on bitcoin available, you will find what you need there!

have a nice

Answer (score 1):

The total number of generated Bincoins can be found here https://blockchain.info/pools. Also important for me to see the price of Bitcoin online. History and pricing information for one BTC you can look at http://mining-profit.com/bitcoin-price-chart.